# Thumbnail image switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a div clalled product_main_img that is the full standalone image. I then have four thumbnail images that are underneath switch when clicked switch with the main image to become the full displayed image.

What I need to accomplish is have the standalone image (the first one on page load) change to the image that is being clicked, and then have the standalone image move into the thumbnail section.

I have the thumbnails moving into the main div area, but the standalone image is then disappearing.

```
    div class="product_visuals">
        <div class="product_main_img">
            <div class="main_img_switch"><img src="/images/main_img.jpg"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="product_selection">
            <div class="product_details">
                <img src="/images/img_01.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img src="/images/img_02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img src="/images/img_03.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img src="/images/img_04.jpg">
            </div>
        </div
```

script:

```
    $('.product_details img').click(function() {
        $('.main_img_switch img').attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    });
```

Comment: protip: `this.src` jQuery is massive overhead when the normal DOM object works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save a reference of the standalone image in a variable, something like this:

```
$('.product_details img').click(function() {
    var mainImg = $('.main_img_switch img');
    var tempSrc = mainImg.attr("src");
    mainImg.attr("src", this.src));
    this.src = tempSrc;
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I didn't know you could attach a image to a variable. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help, so, accept the answer so your question won't be listed as unanswered